# How fix red error line below cy. And cypress. Keyword

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

The red error line are coming below cy. And Cypress. Keywords. How to resolve that issue???

No error line will come below thhat keywords

Comment: Can you include more information? Is there a specific keyword that is failing? Have you installed Cypress?

Comment: Yes, I installed cypress.. execution is part also working fine... But when I am opening the ts file that time 'cy' keyword are throwing error.